Jolt to change the key/values into code/values dynamically
I have following input JSON and want to convert these keys/values into codes/values, and need to convert the ts(timestamp) into CET time. These x1,x2,.... keys are dynamic. They can be like y1, y2...., etc and no of keys also dynamic.
Input JSON :
[
  {
    "x1": 29.684,
    "tz_offset": 3600,
    "x2": 29.957,
    "x3": -0.001,
    "x4": 0.041,
    "ts": 1727870442,
    "machine_name": "SL Station"
  }
]


Expected Output JSON :
{
  "Date": "2024-10-02 12:00:42",
  "data": [
    {
      "code": "x1",
      "value": 29.684
    },
    {
      "code": "x2",
      "value": 29.957
    },
    {
      "code": "x3",
      "value": -0.001
    },
    {
      "code": "x4",
      "value": 0.041
    }
  ],
  "machinename": "SL Station"
}

Could you please help in this. Thank you

You can use the processors in this order :

GetFile
Assumingly your JSON input is kept as a .json file
Be careful to set Keep Source File option to true

EvaluateJsonPath

Destination is set to flowfile-attribute
Added ts property is set to $[0].ts to be processed within the upcoming processor(eg.JoltTransformJSON)

JoltTransformJSON
Jolt Transform DSL option
should be chain with the following
Jolt Specification :
[
  {//date conversion from unix epoch to standard timestamp
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ts": "${ts:multiply(1000):format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', 'CET')}"
      }
    }
  },
  { //get rid of the "tz_offset" attribute 
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "tz_offset": ""
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "ts": "Date", //rename the attribute
        "*": {
          "$": "data[#2].code",
          "@": "data[#2].value"
        },
        "m*_*": "m&(0,1)&(0,2)" //convert to "machinename", eg. without underscore
      }
    }
  }
]



whole picture would be like this :


thank you, Barbaros Özhan.  This works as expected.

No worries @casper , take care.
